# Gitlab backups - multiple per day

Tags: cron, gitlab, rake

We have used a working once per day at 2am backup via crontab for gitlab. A project to make the whole backup/restore process more automated was embarked upon and we're mostly there. The one issue we keep running into is that omnibus updates are fairly frequent as of late, and because the backup then auto-upgrade is staggered, our backups are 24 hours behind, and as such, we get version mis-match errors when restoring on a day immediately following an upgrade.

The more complicated solution is build in a version check to our backup/restore script and postpone 24 hours but that doesn't seem ideal without adding more complexity to both monitor how long the job is postponed compared to the set schedule once per week or every second saturday of the month for tests.

The simpler solution I thought would be the best route was to simply increase the gitlab backup frequency and utilize the STRATEGY=copy option detailed [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html). That said, after changing the cron to reflect a once every 6 hours backup schedule, I'm not seeing any actual increase in backup count.

Is there a limitation in gitlab in regards to how frequently a backup can be run?

Old Cron (once per day at 2am):
- 0 2 * * * /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create CRON=1 && /root/datadog_success_push.sh

New Cron (that isn't working as expected - “At minute 30 past every 6th hour from 0 through 23.”) 
- 30 0/6 * * * /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create STRATEGY=copy CRON=1 && /root/datadog_success_push.sh

Comment: If the number of backups is not changing, have you looked closely at the dates? Many backup strategies cull old backups over a certain # and that may be the case here. Is the backup not being generated at all?

Comment: Yeah. The gitlab backup process uses a time stamp in the file name so every backup has a different name. More to that point, if I manually run the backup command it works and creates a separate backup file in the backup location. One possible answer that Gitlab support provided was non-standard cron notation (0/6) and instead suggested I use */6. I have since updated the cron and will let it go for 12 hours to see if that does indeed work.